# Validate dates before 1970-01-01

Tags: validation, yii

How can I validate date before 1970-01-01 (like 1900-01-01)?

When I try to use CDateVaildator it ends with `CTimestamp::getTimestamp()` (I found it with help of debugger)

```
return @mktime($hr,$min,$sec,$mon,$day,$year)
```

where $hr=0, $min=0, $sec=0, $mon=1, $dat=1, $year=1900 which obviously returns false and this fails whole validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTimestamp::getTimestamp() will generate a timestamp for any dates from 1901 (not 1900!) up to 2038. For dates between 1901 and 1970 it generates a negative number. Just tested it, and the earliest date I can get to work is 14th December 1901. Anything before this throws an error. Not sure how to deal with dates outside this range!

Answer (score 0):

In Yii there is an error described [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/189). The solution is presented there but for some reason it's not included in Yii 1.1.14 although it's marked as committed to trunk.

To make long story short - the fix tries to build timestamp only when there is a property in rules defined.

To use it in own project you have to extend `CDateValidator` and `CDateTimeParser`.